# Could not find request_store-1.0.6 in any of sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am new to ruby. I am trying to use AuthLogic gem in my rails application. I had installed it and added

```
config.gem"authlogic"
```

in my environment.rb file and executed the command

```
rails generate nifty_scaffold user username:string email:stringpassword:string new
```

It thrown me a error "git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git (at rails3) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first." Oftenly even though i run bundle install. Why? Please any one help me.

Comment: What version of rails are you using? You should really be adding this to a Gemfile, rather than in environment.rb Are you still stuck on rails 2?

Comment: rails 4.1.1 .Yes added it to my gem file not in environment.rb file if i try to add in that , it throws me an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 4+ versions, you need **not** to include gems in environment.rb file. You should add the gems in Gemfile as follows,

```
gem 'authlogic'
```

Once you have added new gems in Gemfile in addition to the existing gems, you **must** run

```
bundle install
```

so that, your rails application can consider including the recently added gems (here, authlogic gem in our example) in your application. That is what the reason why you need to run bundle install more often (only when you add new gems in Gemfile)

And, please do not add gems in **config/environment.rb** file. That is Rails 2 way.